# Texture Coordinates with NV Path rendering

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to apply a GLSL fragment shader to some text I'm rendering with NV Path rendering. My problem is path rendering doesn't use vertex shaders and I need to somehow get texture coordinates into my fragment shader.

I located an example of textured paths in the [SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering) called **nvpr_shaders** but this example uses cg shaders and seems to rely on the fragment shader being able to process TEXCOORD0. This method is described [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/Mixing_Path_Rendering_and_3D.pdf) on page 15.

I haven't used CG before so I'm not entirely sure how the pipeline works. This is cg shader in the example:

```
void bumpmap(float2 normalMapTexCoord : TEXCOORD0,
         float3 lightDir          : TEXCOORD1,
         out float4 color : COLOR,
        uniform float3 lightPos,
        uniform sampler2D   normalMap)
{
  // Normalizes light vector with normalization cube map
  float3 light = normalize(lightPos - float3(normalMapTexCoord,0));
  // Sample and expand the normal map texture   
  float3 normalTex = tex2D(normalMap, normalMapTexCoord).xyz;
  float3 normal = expand(normalTex);
  // Diffuse lighting
  float diffuse = dot(normal,light);

  // Decide the brick color based on how flat (red) or angled (red) the surface is.
  float3 red = float3(1,0,0);
  float3 white = float3(1,1,1);
  float3 brick = normal.z > 0.9 ? red : white;

  color = float4(brick*diffuse,1);
}
```

Is it possible to set texture coordinates in a GLSL fragment shader in a similar way? i.e. Can I get texture coordinates into a GLSL frag shader for path rendering without using CG Toolkit?

Comment: You can calculate everything based on `gl_FragCoord`. Did you try that?

Comment: That works well for 2D/ortho rendered text, thanks for the tip. Doesn't work rendering text with perspective though because gl_FragCoord "contains the window relative coordinate (x, y, z, 1/w) values for the fragment" - https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml

Comment: Not directly. You need to a apply a homography.

Comment: That makes sense... Got something working applying an inverse mvp matrix. Not quite perfect but something to work with... Thanks for the info. FWIW I'm using something along the lines of `vec4 q = vec4(gl_FragCoord.xy, 1, 1) / vec4(res.xy, 1, 1);

 mat4 ivp = inverse(uProjectionMatrix * uViewMatrix * uModelMatrix);
 vec4 ndc = vec4(
        (gl_FragCoord.x / uResolution.x - 0.5) * 2.0,
        (gl_FragCoord.y / uResolution.y - 0.5) * 2.0,
        (gl_FragCoord.z - 0.5) * 2.0,
        1.0);

    vec4 clip = ivp * ndc;
    vec3 vertex = (clip / clip.w).xyz;`